# Any way to fix this array out of bound exception?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a problem when I run this code I get an array out of bound exception, the thing is that I changed the face array and added "1", and I have no idea how to fix this, can anyone help, sorry if the problem is stupid.

```
  public class DeckOfCards_Rumenov{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] s = {
            "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"
        };

        String[] face = {
        "1" ,"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
        "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"
        };
        String[] ranks = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
        "10", "10", "10", "1 or 11"
        };
        int n = s.length * face.length;
        String[] deck = new String[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < face.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
                deck[s.length*i+j] = face[i] + ", " + s[j] + ", " + ranks[i];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int r = i + (int) (Math.random() * (n-i));
            String temp = deck[r];
            deck[r] = deck[i];
            deck[i] = temp;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(deck[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: which line does the array out of bound exception occur?

Answer (score 1):

Your face array does not have the same length as the ranks array. Yet you use the same iterator (i) for both of them, which goes till the end of the larger array (face).

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped out a lot, I didn't see that